# LWC Quick Action for Task

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quickaction

I'm working on a Quick Action for the first time (ScreenAction in this case) for a Task object. I've created an LWC component, embedded in the Aura component to make it available for Task.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader, force:hasRecordId">
    <c:LWC recordId="{!v.recordId}">
</aura:component>
```

The problem is that in LWC I cannot get the `recordId` of the Task. I've tried using `@api recordId`, `connectedCallback` and `renderedCallback` but nothing worked for me, everytime the result was `undefined`. Why is it like that? Is Task object the reason or is it something else?

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking this component from an explicit record context (like a lightning record page or a record page layout)? Have you checked if the `recordId` is fetched correctly aura component to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWC Quick Actions are not supported for Task object.

You'll get an error when creating a QA for LWC on Task record:

```
Lightning Web Component quick actions are not supported for this entity
```

I managed to get the recordId from a Task record in an Aura Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    
    <div>
    {!v.recordId}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Summary: It could be that your Aura Component does not receive recordId because of some typo in your code, or if it does receive, the whole component crashes because of the LWC embedded inside your Aura Component. Please check both of these possible scenarios.

Comment: Yes, in both cases it's ```undefined```.

Comment: Try this: <c:LWC"> instead of this  <c:LWC recordId="{!v.recordId}">. @api recordId in LWC should get that recordId too. Does it work, or do you also need the recordId in the aura component?

Comment: I only need this recordId in LWC to call an Apex method but sadly it doesn't work either.

Comment: @SFEnthusiast LWCs are not supported for Tasks. I tried recreating your issue with a LWC on QA and got this error: "Lightning Web Component quick actions are not supported for this entity". You'll have to try to create a workaround. Also updated my answer.

Comment: @SFEnthusiast Also - I created a very simple aura component and I successfully displayed the recordId, code provided in my answer.

Comment: So in my case, the problem was with the layout, I couldn't get the recordId from there and ultimately decided to go with the Aura component leaving out the LWC from this case which was the correct decision.